# prevent real-time typing non-number by regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to prevent typing none-number character using regular expression but it doesnt work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CodeField').val('');
    var numberPattern = /[0-9]/;
    $("#PhoneField").keydown(function (e) {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        var inputObject = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if(inputObject.val().indexOf('09')!== 0){
                inputObject.val(inputValue);
            }
        })
        if(inputObject.val().match(numberPattern) == false){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    })
});


<form id="msform">
    <input type="text" id="PhoneField" value="09" class="phoneBox" maxlength="11"/>
    <input type="button" value="دریافت کد" id="SendPhone"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is possible with HTML5's `tel` input, which is semantically correct.

When you add a `pattern` attribute and use the regex `[0-9]{,11}` in combination with the `required` property, the browser will do a quick check before sending the form when you submit the form. In this case, the browser will check if the input contains between zero and 11 digits. You might want to make that a more sensible range, like 9 up to 11 digits: `[0-9]{9,11}`.

```html
<form id="msform">
  <input type="tel" id="PhoneField" value="09" pattern="[0-9]{,11}" required class="phoneBox">
  <input type="submit" value="دریافت کد" id="SendPhone">
</form>
```

Or if it has to start with `09`:

```html
<form id="msform">
  <input type="tel" id="PhoneField" value="09" pattern="09[0-9]{7,9}" required class="phoneBox">
  <input type="submit" value="دریافت کد" id="SendPhone">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code a lot simpler and less taxing (you check for multiple things and apply regex searches):

```
$("#PhoneField").keydown(function (e) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''));
}
```

Which would just replace any non digits in your code with empty strings.

The code I offered would not do the 09 check at the start of your code, however yours doesn't work either. in your code you have:

```
var inputValue = $(this).val();
```

which sets "inputValue" whenever the keydown effect triggers. This means that if someone were to not have their input start with "09" it'd replace the value by  *exactly the same value.*

on a sidenote for your RegEx - it checks for /[0-9]/, which is a *singular* digit. It would never match a phonenumber.
Instead one can replace this with:

```
var numberPattern = /[0-9]+/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove non-number characters on change with a regex.

`\D` means Not Digit and should do nicely:

```js
var input = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
input.onchange = input.onkeydown = input.onkeyup = function() {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/\D/igm, '');
};
```